# Not able to build apk for ionic3 app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, apk

I am trying to build an apk but I'm getting this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project 
 ':CordovaLib'.
     Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)

BUILD FAILED in 1s

(node:16884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

(node:16884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
    Unhandled promise rejection. 
    This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, 
    or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
    (rejection id: 1)

(node:16884) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: 
    Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 
    In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have also set `environment variables` as `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: check requirements of projects using this command
`ionic cordova requirements`

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your project, check it. if it is hard for you to find the bugs, make new project: $ "ionic start myApp blank". do not add any code and then build it. if there were  errors again,it is a problem in your environment variable.

Comment: Thanks...you said that is right..because I made blank app and build was made, i was able to run that on real time device also

Comment: this means there is only problem in my code right?...rest android and cordova setting is proper